# git revert to multiple commits before which already pushed

Tags: git

I have **multiple commits** on master and **all these commits are pushed to remote ALREADY !!!**

for example,

Currently head is abcde, but I want to go back to 9kjhfa.
How to revert to 9kjhfa. 
There are two scenarios possible for me:

1) either while keeping all commits between abcde and askdjf, go back from abcde to 9kjhfa and then after a while I also go forward from 9kjhfa to abcde

2) or don't keep commits between abcde and askdjf and just go back from abcde to 9kjhfa

```
commit abcde                <-- current HEAD
commit easlk
  ...
commit iwqeur
  ...
commit askdjf
  ...
commit 9kjhfa               <-- want to go back to this point
```

`git revert 9kjhfa`  was not working 
I searched on stackoverflow and google but couldn't find a clear way to do it.

Comment: The most cleanest way is to just add a commit that reverses these ones. This is the cleanest, easiest fix. Although a force-push can certainly be done, to drop these commits, the short answer is: don't, unless you're the only user of the repo.

Comment: you need reset, not revert

Answer (score 1):

Dont do it if you need to keep any uncommitted work,

--hard throws away all your uncommitted changes

```
git reset --hard <commit id here>
```

If you want to keep your changes use soft

```
git reset --soft <commit id here>
```

Revert remote master branch

```
git push <remote name> <branch name> -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a reset and force push to remote:

```
git reset --hard <commit hash>
git push -f <remote name> <branch name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following fashion:

```
git checkout 9kjhfa
git branch revert 
git checkout revert
git push origin revert:master -f
```

NOTE: This removes the commits from the git history, you cannot get them back.